# Why is it recommended to lower the pressure of tire when going through sand?

Tags: classical-mechanics, everyday-life

Why is it recommended to lower the pressure of tire when going through sand?

please help me I have tried very long thinking

this question is from my textbook but no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our objective is to not get our car stuck

for that we want  increase the surface area of the tire which is in contact with the sand

we can do that by letting some air to increase surface area of contact and decreasing pressure exerted on the sand by the tire

**I hope it is known that pressure is inverly proportional to area**

therefore by exerting less pressure on sand we sink less

> for example :walking on sand is easier than cycling on it for the same reason.

Comment: Why hide the example behind a spoiler alert?

Comment: what is it used for?

Comment: An example when you may want to use the spoiler alert syntax is if your answer to some question suggests to compute something, and you want to give the answer, but not reveal it until the reader wants to check theirs.

Comment: ok nice thank u

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when driving on a firm surface, we want tires to be as firm as possible because (a) a soft tire is inefficient since energy is lost because the tire is continuously being deformed and (b) driving on soft tires can damage the tires. But in sand or on soft ground not getting stuck it is a higher priority. Partly deflating tires increases the area of each tire in contact with the ground and so reduces the pressure on the ground.